# Red flagged items in previously unopened, unowned containers

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I was playing Skyrim one day, and I was grabbing some random stuff from the containers. I noticed that in one of the containers, a piece of clothing was flagged red; the words  were red. The container isn't owned, because of the fact that I became a Thane in Whiterun, and I'm hoarding the containers of Dragonsreach. Why are these items marked red? Are they stolen - If I take them, do I get a bounty? The container is unowned, which means I can take whatever I want. So why is this item marked red?

**Update:** This is more weirder because of the fact that the clothes were marked red, but it didn't say stolen on the upper right.

Comment: It's possible that the contents were owned, and that you were simply allowed to take some of the smaller things. The more an NPC likes you, the more they'll allow you to take without considering it stealing (similarly if you went a friend's house, they wouldn't mind you making coffee, taking a chocolate, or perhaps a book or DVD, or using their WIFI). I find when I'm liked by an NPC I can take bits of food and alchemy ingredients, but not jewelery or anything.

Comment: Did you put the red-text item in the container initially? Or did it spawn there and you are just now taking it?

Comment: @Guy I didn't place anything in it wouldn't be safe storage anyways?

Comment: @Jim So you found that chest in Dragonsreach and opened it for the first time and an item of clothing in there was in red text?

Comment: @Guy it was a cupboard on the right of the palace where a table is. On the right side of Farengar's place.

Comment: Just some extra info, as long as nobody sees you take those red items, AKA hidden, you will not get a bounty..

Answer (score 3):

A "red flagged" item normally indicates that you are trying to either pickpocket or steal an item. It could be possible that you still receive a bounty if you take these items.

[image: Pickpocket]

[image: Stealing]

Answer (score -2):

save then take them and see what happens if you get a bounty then go back to where you saved

Comment: That's a good idea to check, but I don't see an answer here. Probably better as a comment.